# Multiple dispatch for the constructor method in Julia

Tags: struct, julia, multiple-dispatch

I have written a struct and I want to have a constructor method that supports both vector and tuple input for the argument `barrierPositions`.

```
struct MapInfo
    mapSize::Tuple{Int64, Int64}
    flagPosition::Tuple{Int64, Int64}
    barrierPositions::Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}

    function MapInfo(;mapSize::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, flagPosition::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, 
        barrierPositions::Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}})
        unique!(barrierPositions)
        deleteat!(barrierPositions, findall(x->x==flagPosition, barrierPositions))
        return new(mapSize, flagPosition, barrierPositions)
    end

    function MapInfo(;mapSize::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, flagPosition::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, 
        barrierPositions::Tuple{Int64, Int64})
        return MapInfo(mapSize=mapSize, flagPosition=flagPosition, barrierPositions=[barrierPositions])
    end
end
```

But if I run the following command, it seems to overlook my first constructor method which should receive vectors for the argument `barrierPositions`.

```
mapInfo = MapInfo(mapSize=(4,4), flagPosition=(3,3), barrierPositions=[(3,2), (2,3)])
```

```
ERROR: TypeError: in keyword argument barrierPositions, expected Tuple{Int64, Int64}, got a value of type Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ e:\Master Thesis\lu_jizhou\Learning\DQN.jl:250
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @Shaya Only vector of tuples.

Comment: This struct doesn't *"support both vector and tuple input for the argument `barrierPositions`"*! It just supports `Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julia does not do dispatch on keyword arguments, only on the positional arguments (before `;`). Typically, if you want such alternative inputs it's often better to use outer constructors.

An example:

```
struct MapInfo
    mapSize::Tuple{Int64, Int64}
    flagPosition::Tuple{Int64, Int64}
    barrierPositions::Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}

    function MapInfo(mapSize::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, flagPosition::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, 
                     barrierPositions::Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}})
        unique!(barrierPositions)
        deleteat!(barrierPositions, findall(x->x==flagPosition, barrierPositions))
        return new(mapSize, flagPosition, barrierPositions)
    end

end


function MapInfo(;mapSize::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, flagPosition::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, 
                 barrierPositions::Tuple{Int64, Int64})
    return MapInfo(mapSize, flagPosition, [barrierPositions])
end
```

Note that the inner constructor is *not* by keywords in this example. The outer constructor is keyword based, but you can't have more than one constructor without positional arguments, since dispatch is done on positional arguments only. (Two methods with no positional arguments are the same method, so the last one will replace the first).

If you need more constructors, you must have different positional arguments. I.e. remove the `;` in the formal argument list.

There's no magic in using an outer constructor, you could as well use an inner constructor. Inner constructors are typically used if there are tests and consistency checks. You could write it as an inner constructor where you call `new` instead of `MapInfo`, and avoid the `unique!`, which is unnecessary with a single `Tuple` (and simplify the `deletat!/findall` logic).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you give me some tips or suggested readings for achieving such a function with outer constructors?